# Difference between time() and current time() PHP

Tags: php, time

I'm currently creating a subscription membership for my website.

I'm storing the date their subscription started in my database  using time() (not extra parameters)

If not, how can i find the number of days between the current time() and the time() stored in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: most databases have a datetime data type and plenty of useful functions to make dealing with time easy.  Why are you storing a unix timestamp when a richer option is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between them is the number of seconds.

There are 3600*24 seconds in a day. Math works here too. Who knew.

Comment: ok sorry, I didn't understand the complete functionality of time()

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: that's 86400 if you're curious. It'll come up a lot if you do date comparisons with any frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `microtime` instead to store and compare it:

```
$diff = ($micro_time_from_db - microtime());
echo date('d', strtotime($diff));
```